# Getting error in awk Print

Tags: awk

I have a dataset with many missing values as 9999, 9000 etc. Part of the data is

```
input.txt
30
9999
10
40
23
44
9000
9999
31
.
.
```

I would like to print the same column with the following criteria.

```
if $1 < 9000 then no change, else $1+100
```

Desire output is

```
ofile.txt
130
9999
110
140
123
144
9000
9999
131
.
.
```

I was trying with the following, but can't success.

```
awk 'if ($1<9000) {printf "%7s\n", $+100}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{if ($1<9000) $1=$1+100; printf "%-7s\n", $1}' input.txt
130    
9999   
110    
140    
123    
144    
9000   
9999   
131
```

How it works:

- `if ($1<9000) $1=$1+100`

  If the number in the first column is less than 9000, then 100 is added to it.
- `printf "%-7s\n", $1`

  The new number, whatever it is, is printed out in format `%-7s`.

  Your sample code used `%7s` which would produce right-justified output.  Your desired output, by contrast, is left-justified.  That is why I changed to format to `%-7s`.

If you are not interested in special format strings, then the code can be simplified to (hat tip: jaypal singh):

```
awk '$1<9000{$1+=100}1' input.txt
```

Comment: Won't `awk '$1<9000{$1+=100}1' file` suffice or may be I missed something?

Comment: @jaypalsingh Unless the OP does have a need for the `7s` format, then, yes, that works: added to the answer.  Thanks.